# Automatic Generate Input without shift+enter Mathematica 10

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a little problem with my program. I have a function which is call `funkcja` where I do some small operations and at the end an output is show by Graphics function.

Then, in function `Manipulate`, I use my `funkcja` and some boxes to manipulate in parameters of my function.

The issue is that I can't make it automatically show output of `funkcja` when I open my project, without pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Is there any way to make this automatic when I open my project?

Currently I have this when I open my project:
http://postimg.org/image/5o1qcxkjb/

This is what I want to have when I open my project:
http://postimg.org/image/f3kxhlosf/

Comment: See this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13248/363

Comment: Take a look at `SaveDefinitions` or put `funkcja` in `Initialization:>(..)` of `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1):

To my understand, you have to press keyboard to run the code in Mathematica .nb file.

However, if you want to be automatic without press the keyboard, you can export your Mathematica .nb file to .CDF standlone file(under menu there is a export). As a .CDF you dont need to press keyboard to run the code.

Hope this would help.

Comment: this is good if the  code is locked down --  you will only be able to run it and not do any sort of editing/manipulation.